# What HTTP headers/responses trigger the "onerror" handler on a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm inserting a `script` tag into the DOM like so (think JSONP):

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "http://abc.com/js/j.js";
s.onerror = function() {
   alert("Error loading script tag!");
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Now, I know a `404` response from `abc.com` for the script above would trigger that event... What other headers/responses would cause the `script` tag to throw an error?  I'd imagine it varies a little bit by browser, but if anyone has any sort of list that would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: When I create and refer a PHP file in which I have set the response code to 404, the `onerror` does not fire, whereas referring to a file that just doesn't exist does throw the `onerror`.

Comment: Update: Might be because `Content-length` is still sent in my PHP file, but cannot seem to remove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

4xx and 5xx should result in an error - at least they are defined as error codes.

[edit] Just tested it in Fx 3.5 - that's the correct statement.

Here's the test code if you want to test other browsers (quick and dirty...)

```
var codes = [100, 101, 102, 122, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 226, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410], 411, 411, 412, 413,414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 444, 449, 450, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510 ];

            $(codes).each(function() {
                var s = document.createElement('script');
                s.src = "http://localhost/test.php?code="+this;
                var cd = this;
                s.onerror = function() {
                    document.write(cd+',')
                };
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);

            });
```

And php code:

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.0 '.$_GET['code'].' OK'); ?>
```

Comment: This actually only causes an error for `407` in my Chrome/Apache environment.

Comment: This is what I get using the code above in Firefox:
`300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,409,410,` `408,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,` `444,449,450,499,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,411,` But the 3xx should be because I don't provide a Location header

Comment: Yes, in Firefox more errors are thrown. Not sure why though. According to the specs, `onerror` should be fired when there is 'an error' during load. I guess this is browser-dependent as to how this in interpreted. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/scripting-1.html#script